# Divergence theorem - Simple question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have just started to learn divergence theorem and having problems doing the following question, anyone please help?

[Divergence theorem - Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YebW.jpg)

It did not mention what is the F, so I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: It would be kinder to your Readers to give a self-contained presentation of the problem, rather than just a link to the theorem/problem combination.  Mathematical expressions can be posted here using [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$.  If this seems daunting, take a first stab and I think many Readers will be happy to help with the math formatting details.

Comment: To expand on what @hardmath said, you can right-click on the integral at the top of my answer and then choose Show Math As | TeX Commands, copy and paste it into your post, and surround it with dollar signs, then you will have that pretty expression in your question! Also if you like an answer you receive, you can upvote it or mark it as the accepted answer, increasing the answerer's reputation. Don't forget, there are poor worlds in the Klingon empire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, usually they give you a difficult surface integral and ask you to convert it to a volume integral via the divergence theorem. But here you are tasked with converting
$$\int\int\int_Vz^2d^3V$$
where the volume $V$ is the unit sphere into a surface integral. First we need to parameterize the surface of the unit sphere in terms of two variables, and spherical coordinates are very nice for this purpose. Along the surface, let
$$\vec r=\langle\cos\theta\sin\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\phi\rangle$$
Then a differential along the surface is
$$d\vec r=\langle-\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta\sin\phi,0\rangle d\theta+\langle\cos\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\cos\phi,-\sin\phi\rangle d\phi$$
The cross product of the two separate surface differentials is the vector area element:
$$\begin{align}d^2\vec A & =\pm\langle-\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta\sin\phi,0\rangle d\theta\times\langle\cos\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\cos\phi,-\sin\phi\rangle d\phi\\
 & =\pm\langle-\cos\theta\sin^2\phi,-\sin\theta\sin^2\phi,-\sin\phi\cos\phi\rangle d\theta d\phi\\
 & =\langle\cos\theta\sin\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\phi\rangle\sin\phi d\theta d\phi\end{align}$$
Where we have chosen the sign that makes $d^2\vec A$ point out of the volume. Then we have to find a vector $\vec F$ such that $\vec\nabla\cdot\vec F=z^2$. We have wide latitude in our decision here, but let's go with $$\vec F=xz^2\hat i=\langle\cos\theta\sin\phi\cos^2\phi,0,0\rangle$$
the way we have parameterized the surface. Then
$$\begin{align}\int\int\int_Vz^2d^3V & =\int\int_S\vec F\cdot d^2\vec A\\
 & =\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\langle\cos\theta\sin\phi\cos^2\phi,0,0\rangle\cdot\langle\cos\theta\sin\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\phi\rangle\sin\phi d\phi d\theta\\
 & =\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\cos^2\theta\sin^3\phi\cos^2\phi d\phi d\theta\\
 & = (2\pi)\left(\frac12\right)\left(\frac4{15}\right)=\frac{4\pi}{15}\end{align}$$
Where we have used the average value of $\cos^2\theta$ of $\frac12$ and 
$$\int_0^{\pi}\sin^3\phi\cos^2\phi d\phi=\int_0^{\pi}\sin\phi(1-\cos^2\phi)\cos^2\phi d\phi=\left[-\frac13\cos^3\phi+\frac15\cos^5\phi\right]_0^{\pi}=\frac4{15}$$

Comment: Great, very clear. Thank you!!